# PHP segmentation fault | __get called inside the class for a protected property?

Tags: php, segmentation-fault

I have a class with the methods __toString and __get and some protected properties such as "message". So far, so good.

The problem now is that I need to access $this->message in __toString, and this causes (NOT ALWAYS BUT OFTEN) a segmentation fault when (see following example) $display_all is set to true. Do you know why and how to fix it ?

Thanks a lot !
Rolf

PS: here is an example

```
class FuckedClass {
    protected $file;
    protected $line;
    protected $display_all;
    protected $message;

    //[...]

    /**
     * Magic getter
     * @param String $name
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($name) {
        return  (in_array($name,array_keys(get_class_vars(__CLASS__))))?
                    $this->$name : null;
    }
    /**
     * Formats
     */
    public function __toString() {
        $message = $this->message . ($this->display_all) ?
                 '[ Location: '.$this->file.' @ line '.$this->line.' ]':
                 '';
        $text =<<<PLAIN
Error : {$message}
PLAIN;
        return $text;
    }
}

//instantiated $fucked_class
die($fucked_class);
```

Comment: Can you post a short script to exemplify the problem?

Comment: @Rolf Works fine here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/qzOJNL Try updating PHP

Comment: yeah, the problem was from somewhere else, sorry for disturbing you...

Comment: If your using php 5.2, there might be problem with get_class_vars, more at http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php.

Comment: hmm ? I do not see any problem related to 5.2 there...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `__toString` is just a method called when variable is being typed to string, or the method itself is called. It behaves as any other class method, so this code must work:

```
class Foo {
    protected $message = "bar";

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->message;
    }
}
```

Or you may have some problem in the __get, please post it's contend and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: hi Mikulas, it's posted now :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, the problem was from somewhere else, I had something like

public function setDisplayAll(boolean $value), and it seems that this boolean typing for the method argument was triggering an error (and this class was used to manage errors ...)

sorry, thanks for your help anyway and have a good day !